# AngularJS ngAnimate and animate.css

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

I have been trying to get my animation to work properly using AngularJS and animate.css.
So, I created the **SASS** like this:

```
.slide-animate {
    &.ng-enter, 
    &.ng-leave{
    }

    &.ng-enter {
        -webkit-animation: bounceIn 1s;
           -moz-animation: bounceIn 1s;
             -o-animation: bounceIn 1s;
                animation: bounceIn 1s;

        &.ng-enter-active {
        }
    }

    &.ng-leave {    
        -webkit-animation: zoomOutLeft 1s;
           -moz-animation: zoomOutLeft 1s;
             -o-animation: zoomOutLeft 1s;
                animation: zoomOutLeft 1s;

        &.ng-leave-active {
        }
    }
 }
```

When my page loads, I get the **bounceIn** animation and when I press a link, I get the **zoomOutLeft** animation, but the view that loads has no animation. 
If I reload that view when the browser loads, it does the **bounceIn** animation.

Can someone tell me from that concise description what might be going wrong?

my html just looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="Content/foundation/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/foundation/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-app="sapphire">
    <section class="slide-animate" ng-view></section>

    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app/services.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to put a sample code in plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. First of all, I added background colors to **.ng-enter** and **.ng-leave** and I saw that the content for the enter was being pushed underneath the content for leave, so I thought I would play around and this is what I came up with:

```
.slide-animate {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    &.ng-enter, 
    &.ng-leave{
    }

    &.ng-enter {
        -webkit-animation: fadeIn 2s;
           -moz-animation: fadeIn 2s;
             -o-animation: fadeIn 2s;
                animation: fadeIn 2s;

        &.ng-enter-active {
        }
    }

    &.ng-leave {    
        z-index: -1;
        -webkit-animation: zoomOutLeft 1s;
           -moz-animation: zoomOutLeft 1s;
             -o-animation: zoomOutLeft 1s;
                animation: zoomOutLeft 1s;

        &.ng-leave-active {
        }
    }
 }
```

Because I set the **z-index** to **-1**, it will appear under the enter frame. The actual **.slide-animate** I set to absolute and filled the screen simply because **angular** seems to create a second **view** when loading in new content and removes the old one after it has all completed. So setting the **position** to **absolute** allowed the content to sit on top of each other.